# Extract colours from user uploaded SVG file and output for use in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to build a page for users to rebrand our system with simple logo and colour changes.

Users will be able to upload their logo and if they choose an SVG the page would ideally list the colours used within their logo as a handy reference so they can copy those across into the other fields on the page to save them having to dig out hex codes etc.

Is it possible, using jQuery/JS/Regex to find and output the fill colours from within a chosen/uploaded SVG file?

I'm not interested in complications such as opacity and effects, just a simple extraction of colour codes as a progressive enhancement. The user will also be able to choose their own colours as a fallback in addition to what is found in the SVG.

I don't know how to get started but I think some of the issues I need to address include

- Removing duplicate values before output
- SVG security/script injection
- Does the SVG have to be uploaded to the
  server prior to use or can it be used before it is submitted?

Comment: convert the svg to canvas and read the colours off the canvas

Comment: @RobertLongson's suggestion is indeed the only reliable way to get computed colors, when you think about opacity mix, gradients and filtered colors, but this would give you computed colors, not sure this is what you need. Also, this won't work on IE prior to Edge since it does taint the canvas when an svg image is drawn to it. You'll have to clarify a bit what you really want to have, and for which purpose.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way of perhaps combining jquery with regex to grab the fill properties from within the SVG code.

It doesn't have to be 100% successful at grabbing every colour in a logo but whatever it can as a handy extra with the fallback being that the user has to input their own colours instead.

Comment: I found this, this morning which almost proves it might be possible without canvas http://jsfiddle.net/P6t2B/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/LZNBgX?editors=1010

OK I have it figured out, I now just need to work out how to put the values into an array so I can see how many values there are and then insert each value into a select menu.

Not bad for someone who doesn't know jQuery?

```
<div id="element1" style="width:250px; height:250px;">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 405 312.9" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 405 312.9"><style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#0000ff;}
    .st1{fill:#ff00ff;}
    </style>
    <g id="group">
      <path id="figure-head" fill="#ff000" class="st1" d="M319.9 6.9C313 3 302.7 1.2 288.8 1.7c-8 0.5-15.5 3-22.7 7.2 -4.2 2.8-6.8 6.4-8.6 10.2 -1.7 6.5-1.7 11.9 2.3 14.7 5.5 4.5 12.9 5.8 21.5 4.8 7-1.4 15.3-3.5 22.3-4.6 -6.6 4.8-14.5 9.2-21.1 13.7 8.5 0.8 16.5 1.1 24.8 0.2 13.2-4 22.1-8 25.6-19C334.9 19.2 329.5 12.3 319.9 6.9zM284.1 23.6c-4.8 0-8.7-2.6-8.7-5.9 0-3.2 3.9-5.9 8.7-5.9s8.7 2.6 8.7 5.9C292.7 20.9 288.8 23.6 284.1 23.6zM311.2 26.2c-5.1 0-9.3-3.1-9.3-6.8s4.2-6.8 9.3-6.8c5.1 0 9.3 3.1 9.3 6.8C320.4 23.1 316.3 26.2 311.2 26.2z"/>
    </g>
    <path id="i" class="st1" fill="#00000" d="M3.6 129.6c2.3-8.2 7.2-12.8 15.7-12.2 10.9 0.1 14.1 5.4 15.1 12.2 -0.1 25.8-0.1 51.7-0.2 77.5 -2 7.8-7.4 10.7-15.1 10.3 -8.2 0.9-12.8-2.3-14.7-12.2C4.3 180.3 3.6 154.5 3.6 129.6z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="element2"></div>


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var colours = $('#element1').children('svg').find('path').each(function () {
  $("#element2").append( $(this).attr('fill') );
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for gradients and filters though does it?

Comment: i ammedned my question yesterday as I am not particularly bothered about getting into the complications of opacity , gradients etc. It's just meant to be a simple enhancement to a brand editor page.

Comment: In that case using getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("fill") would be more robust

Answer (score 0):

Live Code - https://get-color-from-svg-file-using-javascript.stackblitz.io

**Here is the effective solution using regular expression and without any external dependency using plan JS only.**

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");

const SvgImageXml = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 252.667 252.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 252.667 252.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="200" height="200">
<g>
    <circle style="fill:#2B8A9A;" cx="126.333" cy="126.333" r="126.333"/>
    <g>
        <path style="fill:#1C7287;" d="M215.664,37.002c-49.336-49.336-129.326-49.336-178.662,0l89.331,89.331L215.664,37.002z"/>
        <path style="fill:#165C6C;" d="M126.334,0C94.002,0,61.67,12.334,37.002,37.002l89.331,89.331L126.334,0z"/>
        <path style="fill:#F8B242;" d="M37.002,215.664c49.336,49.336,129.326,49.336,178.662,0l-89.331-89.331L37.002,215.664z"/>
        <path style="fill:#D09838;" d="M37.003,215.664c24.668,24.668,57.331,37.002,89.331,37.002V126.333L37.003,215.664z"/>
        <path style="fill:#E45527;" d="M215.664,37.002l-89.331,89.331l89.331,89.331C265.001,166.328,265.001,86.338,215.664,37.002z"/>
    </g>
</g></svg>
`;

var htmlStr = "";
var re = /#[0-9a-f]{3,6}/gi;
var str = SvgImageXml;
var colors = str.match(re);
console.log(colors);

colors.map(hax => {
  console.log("current color", hax);
  htmlStr += `<div style='width=20px;height=50px;background:${hax}'>${hax.toString()}</div>`;
});

htmlStr += `<br/><div>${SvgImageXml}</div>`;
appDiv.innerHTML = htmlStr;
```